# How to delete windows service using display name of the service in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I need to delete a bunch of services that were created on PCs when they got infected with malware.  The service names are random, but the display names are all the same.  I am not good with batch files, so I have no idea how to write the script.

Tried using a powershell script, but could not get it to work.  This is on a Windows 7 machine.

```
sc getkeyname ControlSysService
```

When I enter the code above I get the following result.

```
[SC] GetServiceKeyname SUCCESS

Name = zmzhsirmck
```

Besides ControlSysService there would be about 10 other display names.  I have all the display names I just need the script to delete the service using the display name.

```
input Display name
get service name
sc delete service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this using `WMIC`:

In order to use your known Display Names, you can run this from the Command Prompt

```bat
For %A In ("FirstName" "Second Name" "Third Display Name") Do @WMIC Service Where "DisplayName='%~A'" Call Delete
```

And as a batch file:

```bat
@Set List="FirstName" "Second Name" "Third Display Name"
@For %%A In (%List%) Do @WMIC Service Where "DisplayName='%%~A'" Call Delete
```

*Obviously in both cases you'd replace `"FirstName" "Second Name" "Third Display Name"` with your known display names, (each enclosed with doublequotes).*

Comment: Thank You!  This worked perfectly.  I used the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the cmd as administrator and use the command:

```
sc delete "service name"
```

To get the service name, enter properties:
[properties of a service. Just take what's in the name of the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gFQR.png)

Comment: Yes, that would work if I already knew the service name for all the services.  All I have are the display names.  On each machine the service name will be a random string of letters.  I need the script to get the service name from the PC and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem List of space separated display names using regular expressions.
set "regexp=Windows\ Update ReadyBoost"

set "mainkey=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('reg query "%mainkey%"') do (

    for /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%B in ('2^>nul reg query "%%~A" /v DisplayName') do (
        if /i "%%~B" == "DisplayName" if not "%%~D" == "" (

            echo %%D | findstr /r /i "%regexp%" 2>nul >nul && (
                echo KeyName:     %%~nxA
                echo DisplayName: %%D
                echo sc delete "%%~D"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The code iterates through the services key for the subkeys.

It will read the *DisplayName* value in each subkey to get the date value.

The *DisplayName* value is echoed to `findstr` which compares to a
regular expression string which is space separated strings to find.
The strings will be matched case insensitive as to using
the argument `/i` with `findstr`.
As shown with `Windows Update` which has a space, escape
the space with a preceding backslash.

If tested OK, modify the value of `regexp` and remove the `echo`
in front of the `sc` command.